# how to make axises invisible in victory native?

Tags: react-native, graph, charts, victory-native

I'm trying to build a chart where those 2 black axises will be invisible but I can't find a way to do so. I was trying to use `theme`on both `VictoryChart` and `VictoryAxis` but it's not working. Also I was trying to do that:

```
 style={{
        parent: {
          borderWidth: 0
        },
      }}
```

on `VictoryChart`.

[image]

**EDIT**: I removed those base lines by adding `axis: {stroke: 'transparent'}` to `VictoryAxis` style.